# Unusual Quirk of UNIQUE() function and Dynamic Array formulas

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Recently, I had data of about 150,000 rows, where about 100,000 rows had a unique value in column E.  Column looked like:

```
Column Heading
1
2
2
3
...
99999
99999
100000
```

To count the unique rows, I attempted `COUNT(UNIQUE(E:E))-1` and received an output of "-1".  However, due to a happy accident, I found that `COUNT(UNIQUE(E:E)+0)-1` gave me my expected output of "100000".  I rarely use dynamic array formulas, so I wanted to learn about why this made a difference.

I thought the difference might be attributable to my use of the entire column, as I know that can be problematic with COUNTIFS/SUMIFS sometimes, but `COUNT(UNIQUE(E1:E150001))-1` still yields "-1", and `COUNT(UNIQUE(E1:E150001)+0)-1` still yields "100000".

Could someone please explain to me this behavior?  How does the "+0" within the COUNT() function "fix" my problem?  What purpose is the "+0" serving?

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: I'm guessing that your numbers are really text and not values. ` COUNT()` only works on values. Adding -0- recasts each item in the array back as values.

Comment: You're totally right, and I'm embarassed to have overlooked it.  However, I switched to COUNTA and noticed something interesting:

An interesting quirk - using COUNTA(UNIQUE(E:E)) gets me "100002" - presumably it's counting the blank cells beneath my data as a unique value, but I think it's interesting that it apparently doesn't do this when I use COUNT(UNIQUE(E:E)+0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data in column E is probably stored as text. As COUNT function only counts numeric values, it'll return 0.

When you add 0, Excel "adds" it to each value, and also it converts them to numbers, so COUNT will give the correct result.

You could also get correct result with COUNTA; or making sure data is stored in the right format in the first place.

Comment: You are correct, and I should have figured that out.  Thank you!


An interesting quirk - using `COUNTA(UNIQUE(E:E))` gets me "100002" - presumably it's counting the blank cells beneath my data as a unique value, but I think it's interesting that it apparently doesn't do this when I use `COUNT(UNIQUE(E:E)+0)`.